# WAGERING in DotA 2

Tags: dota-2

Can I wage in DotA 2 if I am not subscribed to DotA plus? I have 1000 tokens but don't know that how to use them.i want you to send me the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You need the **Battlepass** to do the betting and waging. I dont think that this is a dota plus feature.

Comment: It's not.  Battlepass and Dota Plus are separate.

Comment: Yes, they are separate but answer is correct because wagering is Battlepass feature, not Dota+.